# Laravel function take Model id vs function take Model itself

Tags: php, laravel, function, refactoring

I want to know what should be the best approach to make function:

```
function get_total_payment($payment_id){
   return PaymentModel::where('payment_id', $payment_id )->sum('amount');
}

function get_total_payment($payments){
    return $payments->sum('amount');
}
```

what I think is the second approch is save us when refactoring code.

both work but I want to know the pros and cons

Comment: There is really no right or wrong answer here, its all opinion based, it all comes down to, can someone else reading your code understand what you are doing? and what you are trying to accomplish or no? Can you explain your code to someone else working with you? is your code easy to modify or change? is your code easy to upgrade to new version of laravel? But probably, the lesser the code, the easier it is to read :D

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I think it's better to use eloquent scopes to make the total work on many different situations. see the examples below:

```php
function scopeGetTotalPayment($query){
     $query->sum('amount')
}
```

now you can Implement it for different situations. see the examples below:

```php
//get the total amount of payments for the whole payments in the table
$totalPayment = PaymentModel::getTotalPayment();

//get the total payments for a specific user 
$totalPayment = PaymentModel::where('user_id', $userId)->getTotalPayment();
```

In the end, it depends on you. you can either use the scopes or stick with the normal sum. I think that the added value of using the scope in your case is only for making the name clear and to make it work for a specific column.

read more about eloquent scopes: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#query-scopes